# javascript how to convert 090(Number) to '090'(String)?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

how to convert  090(Number) to '090'(String)?

everything I try to do with 090(Number), it will be converted into 90(Number) automatically, so I get 90(Number) or '90'(String). I want the '090'. 090 + ' ',get '90', but I want '090'; plus, 9. + 9, I get '99', not '9.9'. why

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Does '0' + 90 work?

Comment: 090 + ' ' = '90', I want '090', any solution?

Comment: Concatenate a leading 0...

Comment: `090` is not a number. The number is canonically known as 90. Do you want to format any number a) with three digits b) with one leading zero c) something else?

Comment: 090 === 90, true. so the leading 0 means nothing?

Comment: @ted it used to signify an octal in JS but that has since changed to `0oXX`.

Comment: plus, 9. + '9', get '99', not '9.9'。no matter what you do, you can't get '9.9'

Comment: 090 is either 90, or a syntax error, depending whether you forgot strict mode or not. Meanwhile, 077 is either 63 or syntax error. Do `"use strict";` Also, as @sandes said in his very good (although downvoted and deleted) answer is perfectly correct: 90 is a number, `"090"` is one particular string representation of it. You can convert a number to any kind of string representation you want, but the default one is `90` The computer can remember `"090"` as a string, but it remembers `90` as `01000010 10110100 00000000 00000000`. There is no way to remember the number `090` as distinct.

Comment: I assume, when computed, the number will discard the leading zero or the back dot  if it means nothing——not an octal or a decimal

Comment: @Amadan and sandes.... you are right!  thanks very much...XOXO

Answer (score 0):

090 is either 90, or a syntax error, depending whether you forgot strict mode or not. Meanwhile, 077 is either 63 or syntax error. Do "use strict"; Also, as @sandes said in his very good (although downvoted and deleted) answer is perfectly correct: 90 is a number, "090" is one particular string representation of it. You can convert a number to any kind of string representation you want, but the default one is 90 The computer can remember "090" as a string, but it remembers 90 as 01000010 10110100 00000000 00000000. There is no way to remember the number 090 as distinct.

thanks @amadan